# Delete table lines

Tags: tables

I have a table like this:

[image]

and I would like to have something like:
[image]

or

[image]

It's possible to do this with my table code?

```
\begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.70\textwidth} | }
        \hline
        \textbf{Priority} & \textbf{To-do} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Very high} & \textbf{Requirements}\\ \hline
        & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \hline
        & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \hline
        & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}\\
    \caption{To-do-list}
    \end{table}
    \end{center}
```

Full code

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\setlength{\intextsep}{12pt plus 0pt} %%Per spazio dopo Caption
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% package sillabazione italiana e uso lettere accentate
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{manifest}
\makeatother
\usepackage{enumitem} %%per elenchi puntati
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%per numero di pagina
\usepackage{color}

%%%%%%%
 \newif\ifpdf
 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
 \pdffalse % we are not running PDFLaTeX
 \else
 \pdfoutput=1 % we are running PDFLaTeX
 \pdftrue
 \fi
%%%%%%%
 \ifpdf
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {img/} } 
 \else
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {img/} } 
 \fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \ifpdf
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .jpg, .tif}
 \else
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .jpg}
 \fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\java}{\textsf{Java}}
\newcommand{\contact}{\emph{Contact}}
\newcommand{\corecl}{\texttt{corecl}}
\newcommand{\medcl}{\texttt{medcl}}
\newcommand{\msgcl}{\texttt{msgcl}}
\newcommand{\android}{\texttt{Android}}
\newcommand{\dsl}{\texttt{DSL}}
\newcommand{\jazz}{\texttt{Jazz}}
\newcommand{\rtc}{\texttt{RTC}}
\newcommand{\ide}{\texttt{Contact-ide}}
\newcommand{\xtext}{\texttt{XText}}
\newcommand{\xpand}{\texttt{Xpand}}
\newcommand{\xtend}{\texttt{Xtend}}
\newcommand{\pojo}{\texttt{POJO}}
\newcommand{\junit}{\texttt{JUnit}}

\newcommand{\action}[1]{\texttt{#1}\xspace}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\small{\texttt{#1}}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\codescript}[1]{{\scriptsize{\texttt{#1}}}\xspace}

% Cross-referencing
\newcommand{\labelsec}[1]{\label{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xs}[1]{\sectionname~\ref{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsp}[1]{\sectionname~\ref{sec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{sec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelssec}[1]{\label{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xss}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xssp}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{ssec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{ssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelsssec}[1]{\label{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsss}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\xsssp}[1]{\subsectionname~\ref{sssec:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{sssec:#1}}
\newcommand{\labelfig}[1]{\label{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\xf}[1]{\figurename~\ref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\xfp}[1]{\figurename~\ref{fig:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{fig:#1}}
\newcommand{\labeltab}[1]{\label{tab:#1}}
\newcommand{\xt}[1]{\tablename~\ref{tab:#1}}
\newcommand{\xtp}[1]{\tablename~\ref{tab:#1} \onpagename~\pageref{tab:#1}}
% Category Names
\newcommand{\sectionname}{Section}
\newcommand{\subsectionname}{Subsection}
\newcommand{\sectionsname}{Sections}
\newcommand{\subsectionsname}{Subsections}
\newcommand{\secname}{\sectionname}
\newcommand{\ssecname}{\subsectionname}
\newcommand{\secsname}{\sectionsname}
\newcommand{\ssecsname}{\subsectionsname}
\newcommand{\onpagename}{on page}

\newcommand{\xauthA}{Nicola Casadei}
\newcommand{\xauthB}{Marco Benedetti}
\newcommand{\xauthC}{Erica Marchi}
\newcommand{\xauthD}{Mattia Ricci}
\newcommand{\xfaculty}{II Faculty Engineering and Informatic Science}
\newcommand{\xunibo}{Alma Mater Studiorum -- University of Bologna}
\newcommand{\xaddrCE}{via Sacchi 3}
\newcommand{\xcityCE}{47023 Cesena, Italy}

%%% \newcommand{\todo}[1]{\bf{TODO:}\emph{#1}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\noexpand\protect\noexpand\authcount{\the\c@auco}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{author}{\toc@uthor}%
}{% Replace by 'nothing'
}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failed}}

\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{%
  \if!\the\toctitle!\addcontentsline{toc}{title}{\@title}\else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{title}{\the\toctitle}\fi
}{%
  % Replace by nothing
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed patching!}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

%% \begin{abstract}
%% \footnotesize
%%This a Latex template to be used for the reports of Software Engineering.
%%\keywords{Software engineering, managed software development, reports, ....}
%%\end{abstract}

%%% \sloppy

%===========================================================================
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Intro}
\labelsec{Intro}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.70\textwidth} | }
    \hline
    \textbf{Priority} & \textbf{To-do} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Very high} & \textbf{Requirements}\\ \hline
    & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \hline
    & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \hline
    & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}\\
\caption{To-do-list}
\end{table}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Replace `\hline` with `\cline{2-2}` for the relevant cases

Comment: You can (and should) replace all these lines `\newif\ifpdf
 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
 \pdffalse % we are not running PDFLaTeX
 \else
 \pdfoutput=1 % we are running PDFLaTeX
 \pdftrue
 \fi
%%%%%%%
 \ifpdf
 \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {img/} } 
 \else
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicspath{ {img/} } 
 \fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \ifpdf
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .jpg, .tif}
 \else
 \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .jpg}
 \fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%` by a single `\usepackage{graphicx}\graphicspath{ {img/} }`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in the comments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- can you please provide an answer, just for the record.  (see [What is the etiquette for providing an answer already in the comments?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7248/579) for my motivation.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Apparently, I am too late

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- well it *did* get and answer before it was closed.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry :)

Comment: @samcarter: I will *never* forgive you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for the `multirow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.70\textwidth} | }
    \hline
    \textbf{Priority} & \textbf{To-do} \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Very high}} & \textbf{Requirements}\\ \cline{2-2}
    & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \cline{2-2}
    & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \cline{2-2}
    & xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
    \caption{To-do-list}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[I replaced `\begin{center}...\end{center}` by `\centering` as the former adds additional spacing.